# Google Virtual Keyboard As a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, google-api

I've been trying to use Google's virtual keyboard as a bookmarklet using this API  http://code.google.com/apis/language/virtualkeyboard/v1/getting_started.html

but whenever I click on it, it reloads the page!,

that's my code:

```js
(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=my-key';})();

google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "keyboard"});

function onLoad() {var kbd = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard([google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.RUSSIAN]);}


google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

**update:**
I've got the solution finally, it actually reloads because of:

```js
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "keyboard"});
```

so you can replace this with:

```js
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "keyboard", callback: runKeyboard});
function runKeyboard() {var kbd = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard([google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.RUSSIAN]);}
```

Comment: What's the actual bookmarklet code? If it's just what you've pasted into the question, that's not going to work. Use [a bookmarklet generator](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/bookmarklet.html).

Comment: I did this in purpose to see the code, it wont work as you suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `void(0)` to the end of your code?

From http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptvoid.php:

> ...if you ever do use a JavaScript statement as the URL that returns a value, the browser will attempt to load a page. To prevent this unwanted action, you need to use the `void` function on such statement, which will always return null and never load a new page.